# Constraints on group by

Tags: mysql

I have a products table that contains all the products that can be sold by a seller. It has two columns as primary key; `product_code` and `amount`(product weight basically).

As product weight varies their price varies. 6 types of product weight are available: `0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3`. Product code for a product having different weights would be the same.

Sample data:

```
product_code | product_quantity | amount | quantity
1234         | 6                | 0.5kg  | 0
1234         | 6                | 1.0kg  | 7
1234         | 6                | 1.5kg  | 8
```

I want to display all products, but only once per product_code.

```
SELECT  * FROM products where group by product_code
```

Given the above three rows, this query gives me the first row of the three.

However, I want to return rows with quantity greater than zero if they exist, otherwise any row will do.

What modification do I need to make in my query to achieve this?

Here's my table structure:

[image: Table structure]

Comment: You write: "It has two columns as primary key; product_code and product_weight". Bit in the image i see a key symbol on `product_code` and `amount`.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel sorry for that, just updated my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bearing in mind that you're using a non-standard feature, ie grouping by a subset of the non-aggregated columns, in which case (not guaranteed) the first row is returned for each group...

Do the group by over an ordered rowset that encounters non-zero quantities before zero quantities:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT * FROM products
  ORDER BY quantity desc
) x
GROUP BY product_code
```

Note: The implementation you're using behaves this way, but no guarantees are given that future versions will continue to work reliably the way you want them to.

Also, as per the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by):

> As of MySQL 5.7.5, the default SQL mode includes `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`.

This means that your query won't run on 5.7.5+ unless you actively disable `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` after installing.

---

The reliable, and portable, way is to use a subquery that finds all the desired quantities and joins to that. But you have the added complication that the quantity is not unique to a product, so you have to break the tie using amount:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM products p
JOIN (SELECT p2.product_code, max_quantity, max(amount) max_amount
      FROM products p2
      JOIN (SELECT product_code, MAX(quantity) max_quantity
            FROM products
            GROUP BY product_code) q
        ON q.product_code = p2.product_code
        AND max_quantity = p2.quantity
      GROUP BY product_code, max_quantity) qa
  ON p.product_code = qa.product_code
  AND quantity = max_quantity
  AND amount = max_amount
```

The first subquery finds the max quantity (which is the data you want), then the next subquery finds the max amount of all rows with that max quantity (there could be more than one row sharing the max amount). Since the combination of product code, amount and quantity is unique, joining back to the table using these values with give you the rows you want.

<sub>Disclaimer: Code may not compile or work as it was thumbed in on my phone (but there's a reasonable chance it will work)</sub>

Comment: wou;lld you explain me that x inside the query?

Comment: @BOTJr.The "x", which can be anything, is needed by the syntax which requires that all subqueries be given an alias (even if it isn't actually used). If it makes the code clearer, you could make it a name, like "ordered_by_quantity" or something. But I always just use "x" (for no particularly good reason other than it's the default variable name in algebra).

Comment: This answer runs in mysql under certain sql mode settings only. On the recent versions on mysql such queries are not allowed by the default configuration. Moreover, the query relies on an implementation detail, which is not documented and can be changed by mysql any time without any notification.

Comment: @Shadow duly cautioned in the answer

Comment: So even this one is not a correct answer? like a reliable one? @Bohemian

Comment: @BOTJr.See the manual. There's a whole chapter on this topic, including the provision of a reliable, and very fast, solution (using an uncorellated subquery)

Comment: @Strawberry I would appreciate it , if you could give me the link? :)

Comment: @Strawberry See updated answer with (what I believe is) the proper, portable way

Comment: @bot note that I just updated the query again (I left out a group by). It should work properly now.

Comment: @Bohemian is there any place i could read about these? i mean this works and i am not much of a sql coder.Where should i learn about these?

Comment: @Bohemian I believe I must concur ;-)

Comment: Well, part of the problem is that MySQL does not support *windowing functions* (sqlserver, Postgres and oracle do), which make this task much easier. This example covers the most complicated situation you're likely to encounter - most solutions only require a single level of subquery, for example to find the latest transaction timestamp for each customer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want one row per `product_code` with the highest `quantity` you can use a `WHERE` condition with a correlated subquery, that is sorted by `quantity` and limited to one row.

```sql
SELECT p1.* 
FROM products p1
WHERE (p1.product_code, p1.amount) = (
    SELECT p2.product_code, p2.amount
    FROM products p2
    WHERE p2.product_code = p1.product_code
    ORDER BY p2.quantity DESC
    LIMIT 1
)
```

You need to use the primary key for the condition. But because we have `WHERE p2.product_code = p1.product_code` in the subquery, we can also rewrite it to:

```sql
SELECT p1.* 
FROM products p1
WHERE p1.amount = (
    SELECT p2.amount
    FROM products p2
    WHERE p2.product_code = p1.product_code
    ORDER BY p2.quantity DESC
    LIMIT 1
)
```

Now MySQL should be able to cache the subquery result for each `product_code`. With an index on `(product_code, quantity, amount)` or just `(product_code, quantity)` the subquery should be executed pretty fast.

To keep the result deterministic you can extend the `ORDER BY` clause of the subquery. If two rows with the same `product_code` have the same `quantity` and you want to pick the one with the greater `amount` (which cann't be equal because it's part of the primary key) then use

```sql
ORDER BY p2.quantity DESC, p2.amount DESC
```